# Which inline assembly code is correct for rdtscp?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

Disclaimer: Words cannot describe how much I detest AT&T style syntax

I have a problem that I hope is caused by register clobbering. If not, I have a much bigger problem.

The first version I used was

```
static unsigned long long rdtscp(void)
{
    unsigned int hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtscp" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return (unsigned long long)lo | ((unsigned long long)hi << 32);
}
```

I notice there is no 'clobbering' stuff in this version. Whether or not this is a problem I don't know... I suppose it depends if the compiler inlines the function or not. Using this version causes me problems *that aren't always reproducible*.

The next version I found is

```
static unsigned long long rdtscp(void)
{
    unsigned long long tsc;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "rdtscp;"
        "shl $32, %%rdx;"
        "or %%rdx, %%rax"
        : "=a"(tsc)
        :
        : "%rcx", "%rdx");

    return tsc;
}
```

This is reassuringly unreadable and official looking, but like I said my issue isn't always reproducible so I'm merely trying to rule out one possible cause of my problem.

The reason I *believe* the first version is a problem is that it is overwriting a register that previously held a function parameter.

What's correct... version 1, or version 2, or both?

Comment: Share your hate of the Syntax.  When I get to this point, I look for compiler intrinsic functions or just place the functions in a .s file and assemble them myself...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan VC++ offers a lovely intrinsic, gcc unfortunately doesn't.

Comment: +1 just for 'detest AT&T style syntax'

Comment: I think you can very safely refer to [this document](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf), not only to validate but also getting to know a little more in-depth analysis about the accuracy of `RDTSC` and `RDTSCP`. I hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need inline asm with modern compilers (like gcc4.5 or newer).  See [Get CPU cycle count?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51907627) for a fully portable rdtscp and rdtsc using the intrinsic on gcc/clang/MSVC/ICC

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's C++ code that will return the TSC and store the auxiliary 32-bits (Processor ID) into the reference parameter

```
static inline uint64_t rdtscp( uint32_t & aux )
{
    uint64_t rax,rdx;
    asm volatile ( "rdtscp\n" : "=a" (rax), "=d" (rdx), "=c" (aux) : : );
    return (rdx << 32) + rax;
}
```

It is better to do the `shift` and `add` to merge both 32-bit halves in C++ statement rather than inline, this allows the compiler to schedule those instructions as it sees fit.

**Update, about aux:**
The RDTSCP instruction returns the TSC (in two registers), and the Processor ID (aux) in a 3rd register (unlike the RDTSC instruction which only returns the TSC). The Processor ID is an MSR (Machine Specific Register) which therefore must be initialized by privileged system software, its purpose is to identify which "core" is executing the instruction. The value is therefore O/S dependent.

See http://felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtscp

Comment: Does this not also clobber ECX as well?  If not, I'll just delete my answer and call your good.

Comment: Yes, the "=c" specification tells the compiler that ECX will hold the output, which implies that it is clobbered

Comment: Thank you. The first version didn't mark `ecx` as being clobbered. This register initally held a parameter value, which was used in a conditional which, if failed, called `std::terminate()`. When this was clobbered the condition obviously was checking the wrong thing!

Comment: Sometimes useful to have references as to where else this type of code is used ... hence, for example, have a look at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h#L205 and http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h#L42 (the opcode for `rdtscp` is the byte sequence given there).

Comment: If you don't need the value set to `%ecx` (which can be used identify CPU cores), you can simply use the clobbers list: `__asm__ __volatile__("rdtscp" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi) : : "%ecx" );`

Comment: Concise explanation on why we need the function's `aux` parameter?

Comment: @amdn What exactly is the purpose of `aux` if the function returns the TSC?

Comment: @intrigued_66 the RDTSCP instruction returns the TSC (in two registers), and the Processor ID (aux) in a 3rd register (unlike the RDTSC instruction which only returns  the TSC).  The Processor ID is an MSR (Machine Specific Register) which therefore must be initialized by privileged system software, its purpose is to identify which "core" is executing the instruction.  The value is therefore O/S dependent.  See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtscp.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631856/difference-between-rdtscp-rdtsc-memory-and-cpuid-rdtsc), this operation clobbers EDX and ECX.  You need to mark those registers as clobbered which is what the second one does.  BTW, is this the link where you got the above code or did you find it elsewhere?  It also shows a few other variaitions for timings as well which is pretty neat.

Comment: Wrong instruction. It's `rdtscp`, not `rdtsc`, and any output is known to be clobbered so it doesn't need to be listed. The problem is that `rdtscp` *also* destroys ecx, which version 2 marks as clobbered but version 1 does not.

Comment: Leaving this here for the other SO link which may be useful - though the above answer is better.