# clang and __rdtscp: What is it and what is the error

Tags: c++, clang

Clang had decided to give me a error. It has decided to yell at me for using __rdtscp (This isn't my code, I have no Idea what that is)

```
 error: use of undeclared identifier '__rdtscp'
                        i2 = __rdtscp(&ui2);
                             ^
 error: use of undeclared identifier '__rdtscp'
                        i3 = __rdtscp(&ui3);
                             ^
 error: use of undeclared identifier '__rdtscp'
                        i2 = __rdtscp(&ui2);
                             ^
 error: use of undeclared identifier '__rdtscp'
                        i3 = __rdtscp(&ui3);
                             ^
 error: use of undeclared identifier '__rdtscp'
                i2 = __rdtscp(&ui2);
                     ^
 error: use of undeclared identifier '__rdtscp'
                i3 = __rdtscp(&ui3);
```

I really would like figure out why Clang doesn't like me. Does anyone know what __rdtscp  is and how I can get clang to calm down about it?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are compiling for x86, there is a `__rdtscp` builtin function. If you are compiling for other processing architectures, it won't be available, since `rdtscp` is basically the name of a x86 instruction.

This code works for me, using clang++ 3.5.0 as of yesterday:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <x86intrin.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int dummy;
    unsigned long long t1 = __rdtscp(&dummy);
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;

    unsigned long long t2 = __rdtscp(&dummy);
    std::cout << "Time: " << t2 - t1 << std::endl;
}
```

You will need to include `x86intrin.h` to make the translation from `__rdtscp` to the actual `__builtin_ia32_rdtscp` function that the compiler knows.

Comment: That's not helpful. It looks like it is a MacroMonopoly - I mean Microsoft Specific function. Is it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that - this code compiles in clang on my linux machine. I haven't dug through ALL of the code inside clang itself, but the `__builtin_ia32_rdtscp()` should work on any x86. The `x86intrin.h` file has a `inline` function that translates from `__rdtscp` to `__builtin_ia32_rdtscp()`. Does the posted code not compile on your system? If so, what error do you get, which compiler, and what procoessor/OS are you compiling on/in?

Comment: @user3597842: No, it is not Microsoft specific (nor a macro), but an **intel** intrinsic function, and as such "standard" for the architecture. However, as Mats Petersson points out, the two mainstream open source compilers _also_ implement it as a `__builtin_ia32_` variant, which saves you from having to include `x86intrin.h` (which is an architecture-aware standard header including the other intrinsic headers based on feature availability, in this case `immintrin.h`). The builtin simply inserts the assembly instruction at the point of its occurrence.

Comment: **MSVC defines it in `<intrin.h>`, so you can portably use it with a `#ifdef _MSC_VER`.  [Get CPU cycle count?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51907627) has an example**

Answer (score 0):

`__rdtscp()` [on some platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385235%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a compiler intrinsic for the RDTSCP instruction, which is the recently introduced serialized version of [RDTSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) ("Read Time Stamp Counter"), used for counting the number of processor cycles, for example in benchmarking or timer code.

[Here is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783782/which-inline-assembly-code-is-correct-for-rdtscp) is a way to use `rdtscp()` in C or C++ when using gcc. Perhaps the same approach will work for Clang?

Comment: Not just some, all 4 major x86 compilers support the `__rdtscp()` intrinsic with the right headers, like Mats's answer shows. Also  [Get CPU cycle count?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51907627)