# Why rdtscp doesn't return the core id?

Tags: c++, linux, rdtsc

I have this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sched.h>

unsigned long long rdtscp(unsigned int* aux)
{
    // For IA32
    unsigned long long x;
    asm volatile("rdtscp" : "=c" (*aux), "=A" (x) ::);
    return x;
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int  aux0, aux1 = -1, aux2;
  aux0 = sched_getcpu();
  unsigned long long x = rdtscp(&aux1);
  aux2 = sched_getcpu();
  std::cout << "aux0 = " << aux0 << ", aux1 = " << aux1 << ", aux2 = " << aux2 << ", x = " << x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It defines a function rdtscp which uses inline assembly to call the rdtscp assembly instruction. The TSC value looks fine but the core id is always zero even both sched_getcpu() returned the correct core id and it is not zero. The output looks like

```
# g++ test.cpp -o test ; ./test
aux0 = 2, aux1 = 0, aux2 = 2, x = 231368797247511
```

How can I use rdtscp to get TSC and core id?

Comment: Your rdtscp() function doesn't seem correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783782/which-inline-assembly-code-is-correct-for-rdtscp

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that Linux holds the core id in the aux register?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the **rdtscp** instruction is not supported by your hardware. You might check this:

```
#include <cpuid.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    unsigned a, b, c, d;
    if (__get_cpuid(0x80000001, &a, &b, &c, &d))
        puts("unsupported instruction rdtscp" + (d&1<<27 ? 2 : 0));
    else
        puts("unsupported cpuid level");
}
```