# rdtscp() without returning the core ID?

Tags: c++, x86, cpu-architecture, rdtsc

I was reading the following Q:

[Which inline assembly code is correct for rdtscp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783782/which-inline-assembly-code-is-correct-for-rdtscp)

where it describes the following C++ to call `rdtscp`:

```
static inline uint64_t rdtscp( uint32_t & aux )
{
    uint64_t rax,rdx;
    asm volatile ( "rdtscp\n" : "=a" (rax), "=d" (rdx), "=c" (aux) : : );
    return (rdx << 32) + rax;
}
```

However, there is discussion regarding ECX and issues concerning returning the core ID. If I wasn't interested in the core ID, would it be possible to modify the above and reduce the `rdtscp` call overhead/effect on registers?

Comment: You cannot modify the behaviour of the processor instruction. It does one thing and one thing only.

Comment: You could modify the above snippet to ignore the ID.. you'd still clobber the register, obviously. So it's not very useful.