# Compiler complaining about volatile keyword

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I was trying to compile the following code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783782/which-inline-assembly-code-is-correct-for-rdtscp) question and it fails to compile with:  error C2059: syntax error: 'volatile'

```
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdio.h>

static inline uint64_t rdtscp( uint32_t & aux )
{
    uint64_t rax,rdx;
    asm volatile ( "rdtscp\n" : "=a" (rax), "=d" (rdx), "=c" (aux) : : );
    return (rdx << 32) + rax;
}
```

I was using x64 msvc v19(WINE) compiler without any flags on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: What are you expecting `volatile` to do there?

Comment: It seems to be a GCC-specific syntax.

Comment: Its not my code and trying to compile the code. Also I think "volatile"is used to avoid any  scheduling by compiler

Comment: Is that C or C++?

Comment: @NeilButterworth `volatile` would prevent the removal of reachable 
asm code even if its result doesn't appear to be used in the rest of the program; also it prevents it from being reordered with language level instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asm volatile` is a GNU extension. The qualifier is [documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile).

For MSVC, use the [`__rdtscp` intrinsic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/rdtscp?view=vs-2017) instead.

---

Also, note that you can use the intrinsic in all the major compilers, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

#ifdef _WIN32
#  include <intrin.h>
#else
#  include <x86intrin.h>
#endif

int main()
{
    uint64_t i;
    uint32_t ui;
    i = __rdtscp(&ui);
    std::cout
        << "Ticks: " << i << '\n'
        << "TSC_AUX: " << ui << '\n'
    ;
    return 0;
}
```